# Using matplotlib's quiver on a rotated grid

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib.pyplot.quiver on a rotated grid. When I use (U,V,**kw) everything displays well, however when defining the grid via (X,Y,U,V,**kw) the directions won't adapt.

I am using matplotlib.pyplot.quiver on jupyter notebook with Python3. I already tried through options angles='xy', but it obviously didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
plt.quiver(UbaR,VbaR,angles='xy',pivot='mid')
```

will result in an rectangular area with the arrows being in the right direction. But with latitude and longitude:

```
plt.quiver(lon,lat,UbaR],VbaR,angles='xy')
```

my area changes to a diamond, but the arrows will go in the same direction. Same with the `angles` option on `default` (which is `'uv'`). 
So basically I'd need to rotate the arrows according to the area rotation. Do you know, how to achieve this?

Sorry I can't post images, as my reputation is too low. 
Thanks for your help already!

Comment: Hi Gabriel, can you include a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's difficult to understand what is going on (and reproduce your issue)  from just two lines of code..

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for answering. I think I am going with the answer below. When thinking of it for some time and with some distance, I think it's not a code problem, but with my approach, just as @Patol75 stated. Thanks however for taking your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that any of the keywords for quiver deal with the rotation of the glyphs. I am not entirely sure why you expect your arrows to rotate, simply because specifying X and Y in quiver only changes the location of the arrows. Their orientation is given by U and V, which in your case stay the same.
If you want your arrows to rotate, I would suggest applying a transformation to Ubar and Vbar before plotting. If you wish to plot with latitudes and longitudes, you may wish to check this Cartopy [example](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/arrows.html#sphx-glr-gallery-arrows-py).

Comment: Thanks Patol75. I also think, I should approach problem solving differently. As you said, it is not a problem of the code, but of how I deal with it. Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: No worries, I hope you can manage a way to achieve your goal. Feel free to accept the answer. :)

Comment: Hi Patol75. I actually wanted the arrows to automatically adapt to the grid rotation, but I now just coded a rotation matrix. That'll do but it's not as elegant. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: In a sense, if this were to be automatic, that is probably the way it would be done. If you implement your rotation matrix in a function definition, I do not see why it would not be elegant.